Create a dropdown list that only shows items marked as unused!
I have manage software licenses in Google Sheets.
In my sheet Licenses I have a table that lists all the software licenses we manage and their associated info.

Each row is a separate license
Column A, Selections, is made by joining the Application name from Column B with part of the License number from Column D.  I use Selections to populate a dropdown list in a separate sheet Clients
If a License is in use by a client, Column F In Use By is populated with the name from Column B of the sheet Clients

In my sheet Clients in Column A, I use a licenses dropdown populated from the Selections column in the Sheet Licenses to assign licenses to clients.
I want the dropdown to exclude any license that is already assigned to a client but don't know how.
Using the example data below, my dropdown should be populated with a single selection App_03 - satbghuyd from Licenses!A5 because the other selections in Licenses!A2:A4 are already assigned to clients in Clients!A2:A4
Example Data
Licenses




A                                
B
C
D                                                             
E
F




1
Selections
Application
Type
License
Date
In Use By


2
App_01 - 3f34reds3
App_01
Wordpress
3f34reds3-w4g6fre3s-gh6rrtwsf56
07/06/2022
Client_02


3
App_02 - s34fyube5
App_02
Sofware
s34fyube5r-sdtvf4r5dfhg-76yfrdtg6yt
07/06/2023
Client_01


4
App_01 - s4ft6tgw-
App_01
Wordpress
s4ft6tgw-4fuivc6swhujhfd-5f6tdyhur4e
07/06/2024
Client_03


5
App_03   - satbghuyd
App_03
Script
satbghuydft5rd-5trew6tcft6swe54r
07/06/2025
-



Clients




A                                
B                                                                                                                                                                                           




1
License (Dropdown)
Client


2
App_02 - s34fyube5
Client_01


3
App_01 - 3f34reds3
Client_02


4
App_01 - s4ft6tgw-
Client_03



Link to my example spreadsheet

One way to solve this would be to create a helper column with this formula in it:
=filter(licenses!$A$2:$A$50, licenses!$F$2:$F$50<>"UNUSED")
And have the dropdown validation reference this range of cells. There is a custom formula option within the data validation menu, but this does not create a dropdown, so a helper column is necessary. This helper column could be placed anywhere, more I often like to put it in an unused and hidden sheet so that it is out of the way and nothing messes it up.
Hope this helps! Please let me know if you have any issues with this.
